# PHP script behaves different when $_GET variable is different

Tags: php

I made a simple quiz script and use a $_GET variable in the link to determinate which question needs to be asked, and when you submit it, a php header() starts with the variable 1 higher for the next question. The first time, so when the variable is 1 (like http://www.test.com/quiz.php?q=1) the answer check works good, but when the variable is 2 or higher he does nothing and just redirect to the next question...

Anyone knows why this happens?

Edit: I changed the php header function to the html meta tag and now it works perfectly :)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'Soundtrack2.mp3');
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.addEventListener('load', function (r) {
            audioCtx.decodeAudioData(
                    xhr.response, 
                    function (buffer) {
                        source.buffer = buffer;
                        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
                        source.loop = true;
                    });
            source.start(0);
        });
        xhr.send();
    });
  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css">
    <style>
      .centersmall{
        position: absolute;
        right: 500px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
      }
      .mogelijkheden{
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        top: 50px;
      }
      input[type=submit]{
        font-family: WIDM, sans-serif;
        width: 70px;
        height: 25px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="centersmall">
    <img src="/favicon.png">
  </div>
  <?php
    session_start();
    include('conn.php');
    $sql1 = "SELECT TestResultaat FROM Spelers WHERE SpelerNaam='".$_SESSION['login_user']."'";
            $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
            while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
              $score_old = $result1['TestResultaat'];
              $score = $score_old + 1;
            }
    echo $score;
    $already = $_SESSION['alreadyanswered'];
    $v = $_GET['v'];
    if($already >= $v){
      echo '<span style="color:red">Die heb je al beantwoord!</span>';
      exit();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Spelers WHERE SpelerNaam='".$_SESSION['login_session']."'";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $ingevuld = $result['TestIngevuld'];
    }
    if($ingevuld == 1){
      echo '<span style="color:red">Je hebt de test al gemaakt!</span>';
      exit();
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM VraagMogelijkheden WHERE VraagNummer=$v";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $vraag1 = $result['Vraag'];
      $answer1 = $result['Antwoord'];
    }
    $secondsql = "SELECT * FROM VraagMogelijkheden WHERE VraagNummer=$v";
    $secondquery = mysqli_query($conn, $secondsql);
    while($secondresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($secondquery)){
      $mogelijkheid1 = $secondresult['M1'];
      $mogelijkheid2 = $secondresult['M2'];
      $mogelijkheid3 = $secondresult['M3'];
      $mogelijkheid4 = $secondresult['M4'];
      $mogelijkheid5 = $secondresult['M5'];
      $mogelijkheid6 = $secondresult['M6'];
      $mogelijkheid7 = $secondresult['M7'];
      $mogelijkheid8 = $secondresult['M8'];
      $mogelijkheid9 = $secondresult['M9'];
      $mogelijkheid10 = $secondresult['M10'];
      $mogelijkheid11 = $secondresult['M11'];
      $mogelijkheid12 = $secondresult['M12'];
      $mogelijkheid13 = $secondresult['M13'];
      echo '<div class="mogelijkheden">';
      echo '<br>';
      echo "<h3>$vraag1</h3>";
      echo "<form name='vragen' method='post'>";
      if(isset($mogelijkheid1)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='1'>$mogelijkheid1";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid2)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='2'>$mogelijkheid2";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid3)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='3'>$mogelijkheid3";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid4)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='4'>$mogelijkheid4";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid5)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='5'>$mogelijkheid5";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid6)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='6'>$mogelijkheid6";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid7)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='7'>$mogelijkheid7";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid8)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='8'>$mogelijkheid8";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid9)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='9'>$mogelijkheid9";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid10)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='10'>$mogelijkheid10";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid11)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='11'>$mogelijkheid11";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid12)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='12'>$mogelijkheid12";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      if(isset($mogelijkheid13)){
        echo "<input type='radio' name='useranswer' value='13'>$mogelijkheid13";
      }
      echo '<br>';
      echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ok">';
      echo '</form>';
      echo '</div>';
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $answer = $_POST['useranswer'];
        if($answer == $answer1){
          if($v != 20){
            $n = $v;
            $n += 1;
            $_SESSION['alreadyanswered'] += 1;
            header("Location: http://wieisdemol.rf.gd/test.php?v=$n");
            $one = 0;
            $sql = "UPDATE Spelers SET TestResultaat=?, TestIngevuld=? WHERE SpelerNaam=?";
            $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'iis', $score, $one, $_SESSION['login_user']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
          }else{
            $_SESSION['alreadyanswered'] += 1;
            header("Location: http://www.wieisdemol.rf.gd/");
            $one = 1;
            $sql = "UPDATE Spelers SET TestResultaat=?, TestIngevuld=? WHERE SpelerNaam=?";
            $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'iis', $score, $one, $_SESSION['login_user']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
          }
        }else{
          if($v != 20){
            $n = $v;
            $n += 1;
            $one = 0;
            $sql = "UPDATE Spelers SET TestResultaat=?, TestIngevuld=? WHERE SpelerNaam=?";
            $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'iis', $score, $one, $_SESSION['login_user']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
            $_SESSION['alreadyanswered'] += 1;
            header("Location: http://wieisdemol.rf.gd/test.php?v=$n");
          }else{
            $_SESSION['alreadyanswered'] += 1;
            header("Location: http://www.wieisdemol.rf.gd/");
            $one = 1;
            $sql = "UPDATE Spelers SET TestResultaat=?, TestIngevuld=? WHERE SpelerNaam=?";
            $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'iis', $score, $one, $_SESSION['login_user']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
          }
        }  
      }    
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: Post your code. What have you tried?

Comment: Some variables are Dutch but this is the code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you move the `session_start()` line to the very beginning of the page (ie, before outputting any html, or whitespaces). Because it sends headers!

Also, do your logical stuff before echoing any html. I mean like validating the user submitted answer, etc. Because you are using the `header()` function to redirect to another page, so it should be used before any output is sent to the browser. ie, before any html code or any whitespaces.

A basic outline would be like this:

```
<?php
    //-- prefers it to be the first line, though you can move it down a couple of lines, but it should be placed before using the $_SESSION array
    session_start();

    //-- if user submitted any data..
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
    {

        //-- do the validation, answer verification, score updation, etc..

        //...

        if( $user_answer == $correct_answer )
        {
            //....

            header( "Location: http://wieisdemol.rf.gd/test.php?v=" . $next_question_num );
        }

        //...
    }


    //-- do anything else you needed, say fetching the question details from the database for the current question, calculates the current score, etc..

    //...

?><!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ............
    </body>
</html>
```

And regarding the issue that you are facing, try debugging your code. Say by echoing the user submitted data, line by line checking the data, etc. You can make use of `var_dump()` too to display the data to inspect.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, but i put a var_dump inside the first while loop (the one after include(conn.php)) and the first time (so when v=1) it works and he executes the var_dump, but the second time (so when v=2 or higher) it won't even var_dump. So i looks to me he doesn't executes some of the loops a second time?